# Acute triangles in space.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

$f(n)$ - maximum count of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, that any 3 points create an triangle, where all three angles acute (< $\pi/2$). 
Prove that $$2n-1<f(n)<2^n$$

Comment: Strict inequality on both sides doesn't make sense for $n=2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra whats about n>2?